# How to exclude an empty key from array using php?

Tags: php, arrays, key

When doing a query in data bank I can receive both arrays as result:

```
Array
(
    [] => 401
    [BETA] => 223
    [GAMMA] => 195
    [DELTA] => 189
)

Array
(
    [ALFA] => 294
    [BETA] => 223
    [GAMMA] => 195
    [DELTA] => 189
)
```

What can I do to exclude the entirely line when the key is empty?

I tried something like this, but without success:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if(array_key_exists($key, $value) && is_null($value[$key])) {
        unset($key);
    }
    $array = $value;
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the key is an empty string you could either remove that specific key:

```
$test = array(''=>'test', 'test'=>'test');

unset($test['']);

print_r($test);
```

Or remove all keys that contain only whitespace:

```
function array_remove_blank_keys($array) {

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        if (preg_match('/^\s*$/', $key)) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }

    }

    return $array;

}

$test = array(''=>'test', 'test'=>'test');

print_r($test);
print_r(array_remove_blank_keys($test));
```

Answer (score 3):

The key is not `null`, it is an empty string. eg:

```
$foo = array(""=>"bar");
print_r($foo);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [] => bar
)
```

So you would want either `empty($key)` or `$key == ''` as your test, the difference being that [`empty()` can match quite a few things](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Sammitch! And how could I exclude it from the array?
    if(empty($key)){
            unset($key);
        }

Comment: @AloysiadeArgenteuil yep.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `empty($var)` function for evaluation. It considers these values empty and returns true if provided with one:

`null`: the null value,

`''`: empty string,

`0`: numeric zero. Only if it is not assigned by direct or indirect assignment such as $var=0 or $var=1-1. Note that the zero string (`'0'`) is not empty,

`array()`: an empty array,

`$var;`: an unassigned variable,

`false`: value of false,

`' '`: just a space string.

Answer (score -2):

Keys are never empty. They would have a numeric index. 
So just check to see if the key is numeric then unset.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if(is_numeric($key)) {
        unset($key);
    }

}
```

and you don't need to do $array = $value;

Comment: Really?  That will unset ALL of the keys.

Comment: @AbraCadaver actually, it would just unset the key variable which would do absolutely nothing except make `$key` unavailable for the rest of that iteration.

Comment: Haha, good catch.  If it worked as I assume todd wanted it to. ;-)

Comment: Just noticed that you all down voted me. i wrote that off the top of my head. if i had tested it i would have done unset($array[$key]) as he said he wanted to remove anything that had an empty key. since there are no empty keys it would be a numerical index. I don't think i was that far off